# Counting Credit Cards

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, statistics, permutations

The credit cards (VISA CARDS & MASTER CARDS) numbers have the following properties;

Let $N$ be the card number

- $N$ has $16$ digits; $N = a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}...a_{16}$ where $a_{k}$ is the $k$-th digit of $N$
- $a_1$ $\neq 0$
- $2(a_1+a_3+a_5 + ... + a_{15}) + (a_{2}+a_{4}+a_{6}+...+a_{16})$ $+$ count$(\geq 5; a_1,a_3,a_5,...,a_{15})$ $\equiv0$ (mod $10$)

Now consider the following example to clarify the question;

The card number $N$ is $5529\,4203\,5061\,5465$

Clearly $N$ has $16$ digits,

$a_{1}\ne0$,

and $2(5+2+4+0+5+6+5+6) + (5+9+2+3+0+1+4+5)$ $+$ count$(\geq 5; 5,2,4,0,5,6,5,6)$

$=2(33)+29+5=100$ $\equiv 0$ (mod $10$)

**How many $N$ are there?**

Comment: What are you actually asking about? There is only one $N$, and it's $5529\,4203\,5061\,5465$. Or are you asking how many valid 16-digit card numbers there are in total?

Comment: $\operatorname{count}(\le a_1,a_3,a_5, \dots a_{15})$ is a notation that I am unfamiliar with so I will just translate what you mean into a notation that I am more comfortable with. It's not that you are being unclear but before anyone asks. This must mean numbers greater than or equal to $5$ which appear in odd positions (they have odd index).Or the cardinality of this set:  $\{a_{2i+1} : 0\le i \le 7, a_{2i+1} \ge 5\}$
@Arthur. Certainly the question is about how many valid CC numbers there are in total. As you have said: The other question would be trivial (and boring).

Comment: I think we need a lemma first, to count the number of ways that $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_k$ add to a sum that is congruent to $0\pmod p$ for some integer $p$.

Comment: I am asking what is the total valid numbers.

Count$(\geq 5; a_{1},a_{3},a_{5},...,a_{15})$ means count how many value is greater than or equal to 5 in a1,a3, a5, ... , a15. Just count them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $9\cdot10^{14}$.  That is, there are $9$ choices for $a_1$ followed by $10$ choices for each of $a_2$ to $a_{15}$, and ending with the unique value

$$a_{16}=-2(a_1+a_3+\cdots+a_{15})-(a_2+a_4+\cdots+a_{14})-\text{count}(\ge5;a_1,a_3\ldots,a_{15})\mod 10$$

Remark: The OP's formula looks different from the [Luhn formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) for the check digit, which says to double the values of $a_1,a_3,\ldots,a_{15}$ and then sum the *digits* of those numbers, along with the digits $a_2,a_4,\ldots,a_{14}$.  What reconciles the two formulas is the observation that the sum of the digits of $2a$ is congruent mod $10$ to $2a+1$ if $a\ge5$.